# DataGridView, how to skip duplicates

Tags: c#, loops, optimization, datagridview, windows-forms-designer

I have a DataGridView and im trying to check if row already exist if yes I want to skip a loop from outer "foreach" statment.

I figured something like this, but maybe there is some more optimized way to do this.

(This function is deleting current row, and inserting new one, to not duplicating)

```
   (outer foreach)
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridViewFarm.RowCount; i++)
        {
            if (villageParams[3] == dataGridViewFarm.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString())
            {
                dataGridViewFarm.Rows.Remove(dataGridViewFarm.Rows[i]);
            }
        }
```

Comment: You need to decrease `i` if you deleted a row by adding `i--` after the `Remove` line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove duplicated rows from the source of `dataGridView` using Linq to objects, and set the new object as the new  DataSource

Method1:
Example: suppose that `cell[3]` is `mycell3`

```
var noDuplicationList = myList.GroupBy(x => x.mycell3)
                     .Select(g => g.First())
                     .ToList();
```

Method2: use   `DistinctBy()` in the MoreLinq project

Install-Package morelinq

```
var noDuplicationList = myList.DistinctBy( x => x.mycell3).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

It seams like you are using Windows Forms. Adding this tag might help, in order to get answers.

Never the less. How are those rows created? User-input or form a collection? 
In case of a collection: I would just check for duplicates before adding the to the dataGridView.
In case of user-input: Also check for duplicates before creating a row.